# How to start a program as soon as the computer is idle?

Tags: task, scheduler

I'm creating a new task via the 'Task Scheduler' in Windows 7, that starts a program only when the computer is idle.

When creating a task there are 2 criteria that I want to use:

- "Start the task only if the computer is idle for:"
- "Wait for idle for:"

However, it appears that "in Windows 7, the Task Scheduler verifies that the computer is in an idle state **every 15 minutes**." (can see it here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

My questions are:

1. How these criteria above even matter now that we know that it should take minimum 15 minutes?
   Could someone make a sense from all of this?
2. How can I create my task to execute a program AS SOON AS THE COMPUTER IS IDLE?

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old but this is directed at anyone else that might benefit.

I found a pretty good answer to the first question over here:
https://superuser.com/questions/777488/task-scheduler-what-is-wait-for-idle-for

Although I still barely understand it as well, and so far I haven't had any luck getting the "Start when idle" condition to actually work. It seems like it's intended be used in conjunction with another timed condition.

Like you, I wanted to run a program the moment the screensaver started or stopped (I assume that's what you mean by idle), and this is the only way I found to do it so far, although it's something of a hack: You can replace the screensaver executable with your own .exe (or .scr) that runs your command and *then* runs the actual screensaver (or runs your command when it ends).

The path to the current screensaver exe is under: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\SCRNSAVE.EXE

You can make a batch file like:

```
start "" C:\MyStartProgram.exe
C:\Windows\system32\PhotoScreensaver.scr /s
C:\MyEndProgram.exe
```

If you don't "start" the screensaver then it will block until you interrupt it, and then run the end program. And the /s is so it will start the screensaver rather than open it's configuration dialog (which is also /c, I think).

Then convert that batch into an .exe using a batch-to-exe tool like [this](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Batch-To-Exe-Converter.shtml#sgal_0), which works and seems to be clean. Then rename the .exe extension to .scr and set that as the SCRNSAVE.EXE registry key I said above (which, remember, will get reset whenever you change any ss options in control panel).

Hope that helps anyone.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/538849/74576 and https://www.dcmembers.com/skrommel/download/runsave/ seem like they will probably help me. I got nowhere with Windows Task Scheduler. I think your registry edits are interesting too.

Answer (score -3):

Since Win XP Pro times the procedure is like the following. To run a scheduled task when the computer is idle
1.
Open Scheduled Tasks.
2.
Right-click the task that you want to run when the computer is idle, and then click Properties.
3.
On the Settings tab, under Idle Time, select the Only start the task if the computer has been idle for at least check box.
4.
Enter the length of time (in minutes) for which the computer must be idle before the task will run.
Note
•
To open Scheduled Tasks, click Start, click All Programs, point to Accessories, point to System Tools, and then click Scheduled Tasks. 
•
A computer is idle when there is no mouse or keyboard activity.
•
You can specify a length of time (in minutes) in which the computer attempts to find idle time to run the scheduled task.
•
You can also specify that any task should be stopped if the computer is in use by selecting the Stop the task if the computer ceases to be idle check box.

Since the amount of sensors present in modern systemes this is updated in Win 7. YOu might assign whatever sensor you like as long as he is known to Win 7. On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx
there is a discussion on task idle conditions. This is now a science on it own. The great gaphics adress Your posed problem well.

To tse the Task Scheduler, open the Start menu, type in "task scheduler", and press Return. A window appears with all your currently scheduled tasks listed. Expand the Task Scheduler library on the left to look at tasks in other categories. Examine what they do.

To create your personal task, click "Create Task" in the right window pane. Give it some name, a description, and add some security options. The other tabs assist you create the very task itself:

The Triggers tab lets you specify when the task shall run. This can be  timed, scheduled, assigned to events, perhaps every time your computer boots, or something even more complicated.

The Actions tab is the place to set what the task is expected to do. This could be launching an application, displaying a message, sending emails, or executing a command line command. 
Under Conditions, you'll be able to set certain exceptions for the task. For example, you can set it to run only if the computer has been idle for a certain amount of time, set it to wake your computer from sleep, and more. This is particularly practical, so work through these options careful.
The Settings tab mainly let you choose what happens if your task wont run or takes too long. You can set it to run for a second time if it's missed, otr stop the task if it runs too long, or start multiple instances of the tasks at once.
You can also select File > Create Basic Task if you want a simpler wizard to guide you through the process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I already know this info, and it didn't answer my specific questions...